# Преобразовать тег <security:authentication-manager id="..."> в Java-конфигурацию

Tags: spring, spring-security

Есть проект на Spring. Переделываю старую **xml-конфигурацию** Spring Security в новую **Java-конфигурацию**. Простые вещи, наподобие:

```
<bean id="encoder" class="ru.util.passwordencoder.MyPasswordEncoder"/>
```

понятно вроде как переделать:

```
    @Bean(name = "encoder")
    public MyPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new MyPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

А вот столкнулся с таким тегом:

```
<security:authentication-manager id="preAuthManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="preAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**Подскажите, как эту конструкцию записать в Java-конфиге?**

*К слову, тут видно, что этот тег внутри себя ссылается на другой бин: `ref="preAuthProvider"` => данный бин `preAuthProvider` я уже задал в Java-конфигурационном файле*.